# Html.AntiForgeryToken() fails due to Cryptographic Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I'm posting this because this tied us up for a day, and we couldn't find anything about this solution on the Internet, so this is to save people time in the future.  This is the issue:

If you have an `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your view, even if the method you're calling doesn't have the attribute `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` decorating it, you get a Cryptographic Exception when it's generating the Token.

All the help on the Internet says that this is resolved by adding `MachineKey` into the `Web.Config` or `Machine.config`, which we had correctly set up.  They also talk about making sure you have compatibility set etc, and again this was correct in the config file.

We'd upgraded the .Net framework to 4.5.2 a week earlier which it turns out had caused this issue. We found that in order to resolve this issue, we needed to regenerate the `MachineKey` in IIS and then update the config files accordingly. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.  We were loathed to do this as they were a live servers having this issue, however we did this and it fully resolved the issue.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: I was going to, it used to stop you from answering your own question too quickly, so I was waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd upgraded the .Net framework to 4.5.2 a week earlier which it turns out had caused this issue. We found that in order to resolve this issue, we needed to regenerate the MachineKey in IIS and then update the config files accordingly. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. We were loathed to do this as they were a live servers having this issue, however we did this and it fully resolved the issue.